# Line Spacing (IDLE & VS Code)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ide, python-idle

[When the code is saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3U3n.png)
[When the code reopened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6ZvG.png)

Please help me to understand the reason behind such change. It happened in both VS Code and IDLE. Therefore I assume this can not be related to the application itself but rather my Mac Pro setting somewhere.

Comment: what if you change the line ending of the file?

Comment: Does it mean I have to do this with all the lines?

Comment: click the `Select End of Line Sequence` button in the bottom right

Comment: @N.S. It is recommended that you use "Editor: Line Height" to set the line height of the code in VSCode.

Comment: Thanks rioV8 & Jill Cheng. I did change it to LF from CRLF but no change occurred. However, the option only changed this on the specific file which was open. Nevertheless, no result yet. I should mention that they behave the same on IDLE as well.

Comment: @N.S. -Have you tried to create a new python file and manually enter part of these codes? Does this style affect the execution of the code?